# When to use "ordain" over "order"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, meaning-in-context

In the book *Dune Messiah*, I read:

> "The Emperor has said I must die if I set foot on Dune," she said, making a last desperate effort. "You spoke of this yourself. You are condemning me if you take me down there."
>
> "Say no more," the Qizara ordered. "The thing is ordained."

A common alternative is "This is an order", but here it uses the word *ordain*. I looked it up in the dictionary and found that they have similar meanings:

> or·dain
>       verb \ȯr-ˈdān\
>       Definition of ORDAIN
>       transitive verb
>       1
>       : to invest officially (as by the laying on of hands) with ministerial or priestly authority
>       2a : to establish or order by appointment, decree, or law : enact—  *we the people … do ordain and establish this Constitution* — United States Constitution
>      2b : destine, foreordain
>
> intransitive verb
>       : to issue an order

So, when should I use *ordain* instead of *order*?

Comment: Isn't your quotation an example of meaning 2b?

Comment: Why hasn't the answer been accepted?  Also, +1 to @TimLymington (but no vote because I hit the limit, after spending way too much time here today).

Answer (score 3):

Anyone can issue an *order*, but you need a special authorization to *ordain* something.

The words have the same origin, but *ordain* has a much more official ring to it. It is most commonly used in a religious or political context.

If a religious or political figure receives a new rank in a ceremony, you will often hear that they are *ordained*, and the ceremony may be called *ordination*.

Beyond this, the difference should become clear when comparing the Merriam-Webster dictionary entries for "[to order](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/order)" and "[to ordain](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ordain)".